# CGridView Filter duplicate Ajax requests when using Tabs

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview

In my web application I use tabs and load part of the views per Ajax. So it's possible, that I do load the same `CGridView` multiple times without reloading the page. If that occurs I become duplicate Ajax requests if I use `CGridView` Filters.

The filters and requests are standard. Following images show those simple filter and 10 GET requests if type the search value once.

[image: simple filter]
[image: duplicate ajax requests]

Here is the code of Tabs-widget I use:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
'id' => 'thirdPartyCatTabs',
'title' => Translate::t('project', 'Categories'),
'type' => 'tabs',
'placement' => 'top',
'events' => array(
    'shown' => 'js:loadContent'
),
'tabs' => array(
    array(
        'id' => 'standardCat',
        'label' => Translate::t('project', 'Standard Categories'),
        'linkOptions' => array(
            'data-tab-url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/thirdParty/settings/thirdPartyCategoryStandard'),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'standardCatMap',
        'label' => Translate::t('project', 'Standard Category-Mapping'),
        'linkOptions' => array(
            'data-tab-url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('/thirdParty/settings/showCategoryMapTab'),
        ),
    ),
)
));
```

I guess I have to use `uniqid()` at some place, but can't figure out where. 
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you loading your widget, this is where you should put `uniqueid()` I think: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/178/how-to-avoid-multiple-ajax-request/

Comment: Sure. The problem is, that elements are loaded per Ajax multiple times. But I can't figure out where should I use `uniqid()`

Comment: See the comments in the link I posted there are some good ideas there.

Comment: I've already tried the solutions in comments with no result.

Comment: Seems to me you need to make the `standardCat` id `unique` but you have probably already tried this.

Comment: Sure. It will only make an id of Tab unique, but the rendered grid will be still the same.