# Loading extensions manually and best practices for using Ajax for renderPartial

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii

In my yii application I'm using Tabs and loading the content per ajax with `renderPartial()`. To not load all scripts multiple times I've set `processOutput` to `false`. So I want to load all needed scripts manually once at the index page.

Also I use some extensions on the page. So I need to load their js/css manually also. The question is:

- How can I figure out which extensions will be used on the page and load their js/css files?
- Another problem is: for example, I will use bootstrap extension. The extension has assets folder, which contains many javascript files. How can I import all the files?

I would also like to hear about **best practices** for loading the same content (`GridView`) with Ajax without getting duplicate ajax requests when using Fitlers/Delete buttons.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I figure out which extensions will be used on the page and load their js/css files?

You have to load the files before you use them. This has to be done manually.
Use a function like `require('script.js')` before you access any of it's functions.

Your `require()` method should check if the script is already loaded, and if not perform an ajax request.

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to perform this task for you.

> Another problem is: for example, I will use bootstrap extension. The
>   extension has assets folder, which contains many javascript files. How
>   can I import all the files?

You have to import each file seperatly, which means that your application needs to know all files.

A good idea would be to make a config file: `content.json`.
Your function first fetches the config file which contains all bootstrap-resources. Afterwards, it fetches all these resources.

> I would also like to hear about best practices for loading the same
>   content (GridView) with Ajax without getting duplicate ajax requests
>   when using Fitlers/Delete buttons.

Write a wrapper function around `ajax()` that caches results.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but unfortunately it won't help me a lot. My problem is much more specific. In yii all extensions are registered in the `config/main.php`. However I'm using `renderPartial` for rendering `TbGridView` with `processOutput` paramater set to `false`. That means that all scripts won't be loaded (for preventing duplicating Ajax requests).

This problem refers to my older question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071419/cgridview-filter-duplicate-ajax-requests-when-using-tabs