# Filter CGridView (TbGridView) when using uniqid()

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview

For my `GridView` I'm using `uniqid()` to avoid duplicate Ajax requests. 
The problem is, that when I'm using filters the `GridView` will disappear. Same thing happens when I delete an element in the table. What I'm doing wrong?

My `GridView`:

```
         $gridId = uniqid('category-mapping-grid');
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
                'id' => $gridId,
                'filter' => $model,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                ...
          ));
```

Comment: you should not use unique id as gridid, after ajax grid update your gridid will gets changed, so your grid will gets vanished

Comment: So how can I handle the problem? If I load the grid per Ajax - it will be loaded twice, that I don't need.

Comment: what do you mean by load the grid per Ajax ? can you post some more relative code so that i can help you

Comment: Here is the problem that I have without using uniqid:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071419/cgridview-filter-duplicate-ajax-requests-when-using-tabs